# Css background pattern is not working in firefox

Tags: css

```css
html{
  background-color:red;
}
body {
    min-height: 500px;
    background-image:linear-gradient(90deg, rgba(255,255,255,.25) 1px, rgba(0,0,0,0) 1px), linear-gradient(0deg, rgba(255,255,255,.25) 1px, rgba(0,0,0,0) 1px);
    background-position:0px 1px;
    background-repeat:repeat;
    background-size:20px 20px;
  }
```

```html
<body>
  <p>Some Content</p>
<body>
```

This background pattern I'm using not vissible at all in firefox browser. Is this a common problem? Is there any solution for this?

Comment: What is your `body` background? *Edit:* Your body is white and gradient lines are also white. Change either of them.

Comment: It works as supposed :  http://jsfiddle.net/2heyj7aj/

Comment: If it is the grid you mean?, I can see it in Chrome.

Comment: what do you mean ?Im using not vissible at all in chrome browser

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**You put white lines on white background**.

Solution ? Changing background color or lines color :

```
body {
   min-height: 500px;
background-image:linear-gradient(90deg, rgba(255,255,255,.25) 1px, rgba(0,0,0,0) 1px), linear-gradient(0deg, rgba(255,255,255,.25) 1px, rgba(0,0,0,0) 1px);
background-color: black;
background-position:0px 1px;
background-repeat:repeat;
background-size:20px 20px;
}
```

*Be free to call me a brainiac.*

Comment: changing background color doesn't solve the problem. anyways thanks for the answer

Comment: You just changed the topic of your question, so it becomes hard to give a proper answer.

Comment: However, it works well in Firefox too on my computer.